# Azure Node.js App Service in Docker avoid can't open /dev/tty logs

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, web, azure-web-app-service

I'm running a Node.js App Service in Azure in a Docker.
Docker container is default by Azure.

Docker container logs are spammed with logs like

`can't open /dev/tty1: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty2: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty3: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty4: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty5: No such file or directory
can't open /dev/tty6: No such file or directory`

These come every second in ..._default_docker.log files

How to avoid it?

I do not configure Docker image, just deploy the application through Kudu and Azure choose the image and starts it.
Node version 10

Comment: Sharing the Dockerfile and whatever details you have on how the container gets launched (like a `docker run` command, a `docker-compose.yml`, or a Kubernetes manifest YAML) would be really helpful.

Comment: I do not have a Dockerfile. That's the case: Docker container is provided by Azure. It is a kind of default  for Node.js. I just choose that I deploy a node version 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [this MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51b0b0b3-41b1-41cb-9057-e6d2036b0873/linux-web-app-log-files-full-of-useless-errors?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), a fix is expected for end of September or begin of October 2018.

The problem is with the underlying alpine Docker image. If I understood right, you can fix that with providing your own Dockerfile or waiting for the patch.